# Setting selected value in select list

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a Spring form that user fill. That form includes select dropdowns with multiple options.

I must provide a page, where user can mofidy the form values once sent. That means I need selects where the option once selected is selected, and the other ones available in selectlist. Can anyone help me how to set the orginal option selected?

options are type id = int and label = string

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Command form-backing objects, you can use the Spring MVC Form taglib.  This taglib will take care of the binding and selecting for you.  Here's a fairly comprehensive example, although it doesn't use all the annotations: http://www.vaannila.com/spring/spring-form-tags-1.html.